# Formatting long if statements in php

Tags: php, code-formatting

What would be a more decent way to format the following lines of code. If not format any other method will also do.

```
if (
    array_key_exists('type',$handle) &&
    array_key_exists('parent',$handle) &&
    array_key_exists('userName',$handle) &&
    array_key_exists('userId',$handle) &&
    array_key_exists('countryCode',$handle)
)


if(
    ctype_digit($listType) &&
    ctype_digit($listParent) && 
    (ctype_alnum($listUserName) && (strlen($listUserName) >=5 && strlen($listUserName) <=24)) &&    ctype_digit($listUserId) && 
      (ctype_alpha($listCountryCode) &&
    array_key_exists($listCountryCode, $countries))
 )
```

Also, is something like this doable in php?

```
bool fTest1 = A == B ;
bool fTest2 = C ;
bool fTest3 = f(1,2,3) ;
bool fSuccess = ( fTest1 | ftest2 ) & fTest3 ;
if ( fSuccess )
...
```

Comment: Yes, it's pretty doable

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_intersect` and then do a `count` to avoid all the `if` clauses.

```
$arr1 = array("a" => "type", "parent", "username", "userId", "countryCode")
$intersect = array_intersect($handle, $arr1)
if(count($intersect) == count($arr1)){
   //Your logic goes here. 
}
```

Also, all your above "doable" examples look valid to me.

Answer (score 1):

First one have to be done in a loop, possible sugared with some array_intersect family function
Second one have to be split into separate statements each with distinct error message
Last one is pretty doable:

```
$fTest1 = $A == $B;
```

and so on